# Possibility of data race in subscriber callback(s)?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a question on how does the ros::subscriber work.
For example, if I have a class and inside that class I constantly update a specific variable in a while loop:

```
while(ros::ok()) _effort = this->getEffort();
```

What will happen if this same class has a subscriber callback function which also writes into this `_effort` variable? Does it have some kind of a memory lock enabled?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321534/possibility-of-data-race-in-subscriber-callback(s)?/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: no, there is not a memory race (in terms of two threads writing to the same memory address at the same time). By default, ROS doesn't start any threads when you make subscribers/callbacks. When you call `ros::spin()` or `ros::spinOnce()`, it will call each of the subscribers you have added sequentially, in the same thread as the `spin`.

Note about your code: if the `while(ros::ok()) _effort = this->getEffort();` is running in the main loop, then your subscribers will never get called, since (as mentioned above), in a single threaded program, subscribers are only called when `ros::spin()` or `ros::spinOnce()` is called. A slight modification to your above code that would call the subscriber would be:

```
while(ros::ok()) {
    ros::spinOnce();
    _effort = this->getEffort();
}
```

Now if you are creating a different thread to run the `while(ros::ok()) _effort = this->getEffort();`, then yes, there will be a data race, as ROS doesn't handle memory locks for you. For some more resources on this, look around ROS answers some more ([here's](https://answers.ros.org/question/56275/suggest-good-example-of-multi-threading-with-ros/) one).

Source: mostly from http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning.

---

Originally posted by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) with karma: 711 on 2019-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0